# Выдаётся ошибка RunTimeWarning

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Ошибка:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Dispatcher.start_polling' was never awaited
> dp.start_polling(dp)

Код:

```py
import requests
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import ParseMode

# Вставьте свой API-токен от BotFather
API_TOKEN = ''

# Инициализация бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Обработчик команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Конвертор, писать по примеру: 'amount currency_from currency_to'")

# Обработчик всех сообщений, кроме команд
@dp.message_handler()
async def convert_currency(message: types.Message):
    try:
        amount, from_currency, to_currency = message.text.split()
        url = f"https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/{from_currency}"
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        exchange_rate = data["rates"][to_currency]
        converted_amount = round(float(amount) * exchange_rate, 2)
        await message.reply(md.text(f"{amount} {from_currency} is equal to {converted_amount} {to_currency}"), parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
    except:
        await message.reply("Invalid input. Please try again.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: ошибку целиком в вопросе отобразите

Comment: попробуйте `await dp.start_polling(bot)`

Comment: Нет, всё равно выдаётся данная ошибка

Comment: Ну что такое, так никто и не сказал что Runtime**Warning**, это **предупреждение**!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import requests
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor

# Вставьте свой API-токен от BotFather
API_TOKEN = ''

# Инициализация бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


# Обработчик команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Конвертор, писать по примеру: 'amount currency_from currency_to'")


# Обработчик всех сообщений, кроме команд
@dp.message_handler()
async def convert_currency(message: types.Message):
    try:
        amount, from_currency, to_currency = message.text.split()
        url = f"https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/{from_currency}"
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        exchange_rate = data["rates"][to_currency]
        converted_amount = round(float(amount) * exchange_rate, 2)
        await message.reply(md.text(f"{amount} {from_currency} is equal to {converted_amount} {to_currency}"), parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
    except:
        await message.reply("Invalid input. Please try again.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @Shelkovs, если вам помог мой ответ, то можете принять его, нажав соответствующую кнопку слева от него. А если он вам еще и понравился, то отметьте его полезным там же